# R / Excel : leading zeroes

Tags: r, excel, formatting

I am trying to read a worksheet in an Excel 2010 workbook file into R using both the `xlsx` and `XLConnect` packages.  Both are dropping leading zeroes on zip code columns despite formatting the cells in the worksheet as 'Text'.

```
wb <- loadWorkbook('c:/~/file1.xlsx')
sheetNames <- getSheets(wb)

for(i in 1:length(sheetNames)){  # i = 2
    #dat1 <- read.xlsx('c:/~/file1.xlsx', sheetNames[i], as.data.frame = T)
    dat1 <-  readWorksheetFromFile('c:/~/file1.xlsx', sheetNames[i])
}
```

Does anyone have suggestions for how to deal with this?

Comment: Try specifying the argument `colTypes`.  See `?readWorksheet`.

Comment: @Andrie : Thanks, adding 'colType = "character"' did the job.

Comment: @Andrie Can you please post your response as an answer so screechOwl can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the column types as an argument to `readWorksheet()` or `readWorksheetFromFile()`, by using the argument `colType = ...`.

For example, to read all columns as character, use:

```
readWorkSheet(..., colType="character")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also fix this afterwards with `sprintf`:

```
# some example data
x <- c(225,4867,52,15732,9514,78142)
# getting the leading zeros back
x <- sprintf("%05s", x)

> x
[1] "00225" "04867" "00052" "15732" "09514" "78142"
```