# How to use sprintf function to add leading "0" instead of spaces to character?

Tags: r, printf, padding

I am trying to use `sprintf` function to add leading "0" to character, and make all charaters the same length. However what I get is leading space.

My code:

```
a <- c("12","123", "1234")
sprintf("%04s",a)
[1] "  12" " 123" "1234"
```

What I tried to get:

```
[1] "0012" "0123" "1234"
```

The `sprintf` manual says: "For characters, this zero-pads on some platforms and is ignored on others."

My version:
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          3
minor          1.0
year           2014
month          04
day            10
svn rev        65387
language       R
version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
nickname       Spring Dance

Comment: You need more examples before I know what you're trying to do. Sometimes this is ignored on other systems, as the manual says. Perhaps `sprintf("%07d",125)`

Comment: Does this question help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266915/format-number-as-fixed-width-with-leading-zeros/8267036#8267036

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043162/r-excel-leading-zeroes/24044769#24044769)

Comment: It works fine with me (R 3.0.2 on OSX 10.8.4). Did you try to convert your character vector to a numeric vector?

Comment: Couldn't you just paste 0 and your string together?

Comment: As @beginneR said, `paste0("0", "125")` works fine on characters

Comment: @beginneR @RichardScriven When all the elements of a vector are of the same length, that might be a solution. However, when the elements have different lengths and when the OP wants to convert all elements to the same length with leading zeros, than `paste` (or `paste0`) won't give the desired solution.

Comment: If your vector only ever has numerals, then I think @BlueMagister's comment above should be the solution. Note that the [manual states](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html): "For numbers, pad to the field width with leading zeros. For characters, this zero-pads on some platforms and is ignored on others". Just coerce the vector to to numeric first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a platform which only inserts spaces,  regex is your friend. Something like

```
foo<- gsub('^[ ]{1,}','0',bar)
```

That will replace all leading spaces with a `0` .  I know regex can be told to replace `N` spaces with `N` zero-chars, but I forget exactly how.

EDIT: to those `paste0` naysayers, how about:

```
wantlength <- 12 # the desired final string size, fully zero padded
paste0( paste0(rep('0',wantlength-nchar(foo)),collapse='') ,foo)
```

Comment: Slightly more simply, `gsub('^ +', '0', bar)`, or `gsub('^\\s+', '0', bar)` to match all leading white space characters. But it's probably safe to assume that the leading white spaces are the only white spaces in the strings (are we padding numbers?), so we can just `gsub('\\s', '0', bar)`.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I think jbaums's function: gsub('^\\s+', '0', bar) solved my problem.